# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Across Applications Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, forms-authentication, machinekey

This has been the bane of my existence for the better part of a week.

I have four existing webforms applications that utilize forms authentication. The URL for each is mydomain/app1/, mydomain/app2/, etc. I have been tasked with creating a new application that will function as a single sign-on application with the URL mydomain/ssoapp. Once a user logs in, it basically compiles everything from the pre-existing apps that the user has access to, so our users don't have to go out and log into each of them separately. But the old applications need to function as they currently do.

The important part of my web.config is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="frmLogin.aspx?Type=login" name="sqlAuthCookie" protection="All" path="/" domain="mydomain"
    timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
<machineKey validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" decryptionKey="mykey" validationKey="myvalkey"/>
```

Simply adding this to the web.config for all of the applications worked like a charm....for three of them.

In the SSO application I'm creating a formsauthenticationticket, cookie, and adding that to the response with the following code. Each of the four pre-existing applications uses this same code as well:

```
Dim lTicket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket( _
         1, _
         pstrUserId.ToString, _
         System.DateTime.Now, _
         System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), _
         True, _
         pstrUserId.ToString, _
         FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
        ' Encrypt the ticket.
        Dim lencTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(lTicket)
        ' Create the cookie and add to response
        Dim cookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, lencTicket)
        cookie.Domain = ".mydomain.gov"
        pobjResponse.SetCookie(cookie)
        pobjResponse.Cookies.Add(cookie)
        'Cleanup
        lencTicket = Nothing
        lTicket = Nothing
```

- In chrome debugger for the SSO application, I log in and the cookie is created with the correct information.
- I can click on my menu list, which uses a response.redirect to go out to the other applications. For the 3 working applications, I bypass the login screen, go directly to the form I need, and the cookie is unchanged
- For the problem child application, I can still see the cookie however I am redirected back to the login screen.
- If I login from this point, a new cookie is created, with the same name as the preexisting one, however the domain has the "www" prefix on it

Other useful information (maybe):

1. I've ensured that all machinekey, decryption key, validation method, etc match across applications
2. My domain is in the format of sub1.mid1.gov . I've tried every combination of the format for this in the cookie assignment and web.config. Both with and without the preceding dot.
3. I've removed httpRuntime from the web.config as some others had mentioned this causes issues.
4. There are no errors in the IIS logs
5. All applications are running under the same apppool currently

Currently I'm contemplating taking some vacation time so I don't feel bad about crying in the corner on my employers dime. I'm sure it's something ridiculously simple, but I appreciate any help in the matter. Thanks!